# How can I reuse Python packages within GitHub Actions in containers?

Tags: python, docker, containers, github-actions, python-packaging

We have several GitHub Actions written in Python and they run in containers. Nowadays we even have an internal template, it's very handy and easy to use, you write your small script and that's it, you can consume it from Workflows.

Each action is on a different repo, and I started to notice many duplications in the code, so I decided to create some python packages to promote reuse.

**First issue:**

- GitHub Packages doesn't have support to Python packages :-
  No big deal there, I can install with `pip install git+[https://github...]`
- pip install git+ works like a charme locally, but not within the GHA container as it's not authenticated, so it cannot reach my company's private/internal repo.

I found many articles on how to circumvent this by passing the ssh keys to the container or using submodules, but it didn't work well with the GHA as I don't build the container myself, GitHub does it, and it would present a security breach if an action could reach a private/internal repo.

I'm just looking for a way to reuse Python packages within GitHub actions, any suggestion?

I can't fire a way to pass the GH_TOKEN to be used in the Docker build

action.yml

```yaml
name: "soemnamee"
description: "some description"
author: "the author"
inputs:

  GitHubToken:
    description: "GitHub Token "
    required: true        
runs:
  using: "docker"
  image: "Dockerfile"
```

The comments are my tries, but basically the environment variables are not present, and couldn't find a way to pass them there.

Dockerfile

````
FROM ghcr.io/cicirello/pyaction:4.19.0 AS builder
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# We are installing a dependency here directly into our app source dir
RUN pip install --target=/app requests

# RUN export GH_TOKEN=$INPUT_GH_TOKEN
RUN gh auth login --with-token $INPUT_GH_TOKEN
RUN gh repo clone mycompany/my-package-folder
# RUN git clone https://oauth2:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/mycompany/my-package-folder
# RUN pip install git+https://oauth2:$INPUT_GH_TOKEN@github.com/mycompany/my-package-folder
RUN pip install my-package-folder/

WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONPATH /app
CMD ["/app/main.py"]

```
````

Comment: If the repository is secret and it is not allowed to access it on build time, _"No big deal there, I can install with pip install git+[https://github...]"_ is a direct lie, it is that much a big deal as it is not an option at all. Now let's assume this was theoretic, then clashing with reality here inherits the solution: Create an artifact out of the git+[https://github...] referenced package that is available in a public (or private) repository from which you are allowed to run `pip install <path-to-allowed-artifact-file-in-accessible-location>`. Really no big deal!

Comment: hi @hakre, "lie" is a bit too harsh... that was my line of thought and naturally it doesn't work, otherwise I wouldn't be here :-)
I understand I have to point to a repo with access, my point is I don't know how to do it, the documentation for GHA using containers is not exactly the best, and even passing a GH Token to my GHA i can't figure how to make available while building the container. I'm adding my ``task.yaml`` and ``dockerfile`` to help understand the issue

Comment: Okay, this is way more concrete. Please add all clarifications to the question and perhaps boil it down to the specific access issue you have. The idea in my earlier comment was more of a workaround as it would suffice to host tar-files somewhere, but your original problem might retain, so it is perhaps better if you see a way to ask about to original problem precisely, e.g. which token has been tried, does not work, here the error message, what token would be fitting? Read this documentation, it puzzles me at this point etc.